# When I access the site URL where I host the VF page in different browser, The inputfields are not appearing. I can only see outputlabel. Why?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, force.com-sites

When I preview the vf page from developer console, I am able to see the fields but when I access the site URL where I host the VF page in different browser, The inputfields are not appearing and i am not able to populate the fields and create a record. I can only see outputlabel. Why? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is my VF Page code:

```
<apex:page controller="VoucherRequestController">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <div style="border: 2px solid #333333; padding: 10px;">
         <div style="font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 15px; color: #333333;">
        Salesforce Certification Voucher Request - 2023-2024 (Only for WSP)
    </div>
        
        <div style="font-size: 14px; color: #333333; margin-bottom: 15px;">
            Thank you for your interest in obtaining certification. Please complete the following form 
            and allow at least 2-3 business days for a response. Complete a separate form for additional voucher requests.
        </div>
        
        <div style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; color: black; margin-bottom: 15px;">
            Certification Voucher - Wipro Pre-requisite:-
            </div>
         <div>
            <ul style="color: black; font-size: 14px;">
                <li>Admin - Admin and App Builder Supersets</li>
                <li>App Builder - Admin and App Builder Supersets</li>
                <li>PD1 - Admin, App Builder, and PD1 Supersets</li>
                <li>Any new Voucher for B2 and Below Employees - Admin and App Builder Supersets</li>
                <li>Any Voucher for Employees having no certifications - Salesforce Associate Certificate within 15 days of Joining</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div style="font-size: 14px; color: #777777; margin-bottom: 15px;">
            Note: Once the voucher is allocated, you need to take up the exam within 4 weeks. The voucher has limited validity,
            and you would be accountable for the loss if you do not take the exam within 4 weeks or return it within that window. 
            Hence, please fill the form only if you are prepared for the exam. Please also note that you have to be part of the 
            WSP team to request a voucher using this form.
        </div>

        <div style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; color: #FF0000;">
            **** Do not share this form link with employees who are not part of Wipro Salesforce Practice ****
        </div>
        
 </div><br/>            

        <apex:pageBlockSection >                
           
            <apex:outputLabel value="Employee ID (123456):" for="employeeId"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!voucherRequest.Employee_ID__c}" required="true" id="employeeId"/>
            
            <apex:outputLabel value="Employee Name:" for="empname"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!voucherRequest.Employee_Name__c}" required="true" id="empname"/>
            
            <apex:outputLabel value="Employee Company e-mail address:" for="emailadd"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!voucherRequest.Employee_Email_Address__c}" required="true" id="emailadd"/>
            
            <apex:outputLabel value="Derived_Emp_Geography:" for="location"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!voucherRequest.Employee_Location__c}" required="true" id="location"/>
            
            <apex:outputLabel value="Which Salesforce Certification are you planning on pursuing?" for="certification"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!voucherRequest.Certification_Name__c}" required="true" id="certification"/>  
            
            <apex:outputLabel value="Please provide approval from your Primary supervisor as per MyWipro or Location Delivery Manager Name( from whom approval should be taken):" for="managername"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!voucherRequest.Manager_Name__c}" required="true" id="managername"/>               
            
            <apex:outputLabel value="Manager Email address:" for="manageremail"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!voucherRequest.Manager_Email_Address__c}" required="true" id="manageremail"/>                
            
            <apex:outputLabel value="Got Manager Approval for Voucher Allocation?" for="approval"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!voucherRequest.Got_Manager_Approval__c}" required="true" id="approval"/>  
            
            <apex:outputLabel value="Are you part of Wipro Salesforce Practice (WSP)? To check if your part of WSP, kindly go to MyPSP (MyWipro->All Apps->Information->MyData-> Personal Staffing Page) and check if you are allocated to profit center Salesforce or Salesforce-4C( refer below screen)" for="Wsp"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!voucherRequest.Are_you_part_of_WSP__c}" required="true" id="Wsp"/>
                                           
            <apex:outputLabel value="Are you servicing notice period?" for="notice"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!voucherRequest.Is_Resigned__c}" required="true" id="notice"/>                                            
            
            <apex:outputLabel value="What is your planned/estimated date to take the certification exam (between 2 to 30 business days)?" for="examdate"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!voucherRequest.Scheduled_Date__c}" required="true" id="examdate"/>                
            
            <apex:outputLabel value="I have my Webassesor account tagged to Wipro e-mail address." for="tagging"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!voucherRequest.Tagged_webassesor_to_Wipro__c}" required="true" id="tagging"/>
            
            <apex:outputLabel value="I have my Trailhead account tagged to Wipro e-mail address:" for="trailhead"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!voucherRequest.Trailhead_Account_Tagged_to_Wipro__c}" required="true" id="trailhead"/>
            
       
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton action="{!createVoucherRequest}" value="Submit"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

</apex:page>

```
Here's my controller for the VF page : 
public with sharing class VoucherRequestController {

public Voucher_Request_Form__c voucherRequest { get; set; }

public VoucherRequestController() {
    // Initialize the voucherRequest object
    voucherRequest = new Voucher_Request_Form__c();
}

public PageReference createVoucherRequest() {
    
    insert voucherRequest;

   
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: does the running (guest?) user have FLS on those fields?  and Read on the object?

Comment: Yes, Checked object level and Field level security.  Enabled the VF page and controller for the profile.

Comment: if the inputFields are not appearing, it has to be a FLS issue (edit on fields, edit on object)